# Django Models absolute url - what am i doing wrong

Tags: django

I am trying to set up links to a view that allows to edit objects, in previous view.
Model:

```
class List(models.Model):
 user = models.ForeignKey(User)
 name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
 type = models.PositiveIntegerField(choices=TYPE_DICT)

 def __unicode__(self):
  return self.name

 @models.permalink
 def get_absolute_url(self):
  return ('EditList', None, {'list_id':self.id} )
```

View:

```
  lists = List.objects.filter(user=request.user)
  array = []
  for list in lists:
   ListDict = {'Name':list.name, 'type':types[str(list.type)], 'edit':list }
   array.append(ListDict)
  context = { 'array':array,}
```

Template:

```
    {% for dict in array %}
        <tr>
        {% for key,value in dict.items %}
            {% ifequal key 'edit' %}
                <td>{{ key }}</td><td><a href="{{ value.get_absolute_url }}">{{ value.name }}</a></td>
            {% else %}
                <td>{{ key }}:&nbsp;</td><td>{{ value }}</td>
            {% endifequal %}
        {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

and urls conf:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('tst.list.views',
 (r'^$', 'list'),
 (r'^edit/(?P<list_id>\d+)/$', 'EditList')
```

,

What this line with link gives me is http://localhost/list/ as url, not http://localhost/list/edit/[objectid]/

Can anyone please tell me what am i doing wrong?

Alan

Comment: What is `dict` in the template? You're passing in a list confusingly called `array` in the context, but I can't see anything called `dict`.

Comment: Sorry. It seems i left out some of the code. dict is part of the array that gets put together in view - ListDict

Comment: and Value is List object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you *had* wanted to do it for an unnamed urlconf, you just needed to pass the whole import string:

```
@models.permalink
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return ('yourproject.yourapp.views.EditList', None, {'list_id':self.id} )
```

I also suggest you follow the [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) naming conventions for functions.

Comment: Thanks. By mentioning pep8, you suggest that it should be edit_list not EditList?

Comment: Yeah, requiring a good standard coding is one of my peeves :). The ones which stood out: ListDict -> list_dict, consistent standard spacing in your dicts and tuples, 4 spaced (or tabbed) indentation.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I got it working. What i needed to do ,was to give name to this view. When i changed my urlconf to this:

```
url(r'^edit/(?P<list_id>\d+)/$', 'EditList', name = 'EditList'),
```

Then everything started working.